# How to implement a search feature when your link is from $_GET method

Tags: php, search

You guys probably don't understand my question, I'll try to explain further.

I have a site that displays the product information its name, id, price, quantity etc.
Now I have displayed it in a way of using $_GET variable.

Like for example if I want to click the product page then the link would be

```
http://localhost/InventorySystem/Employee/Tools/?Item=ProductList
```

I dont have to make another php page for that all I need is a get method and it will display the product information.

Now my problem is, How to I implement a search function with it? Is there a way for me to create a search function like

```
?Item=ProductList&Search=SearchTerm
```

I having a hard time how to do it. Please any advices.

Comment: Is the page displaying one product or many products?

Comment: Its displaying all the products that are in the database. I'm basically making a search feature so that I can narrow the items that is searching.

Comment: basically add another variable in your query string, like you just showed in your example: `?Item=ProductList&Search=SearchTerm`. and just do `$_GET['Search']` to get the value, pass it to your mysql and implement a filter using the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically add another variable in your query string, like you just showed in your example: `?Item=ProductList&Search=SearchTerm`. and just do `$_GET['Search']` to get the value, pass it to your mysql and implement a filter using the `WHERE` clause compounded with `LIKE` like so:

```
$searchkey = $_GET['Search'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%".$searchkey."%'");
```

This will return results containing the term you passed in `$searchkey`, e.g. if `$searchkey = "ball"` then `volleyball, basketball, baller, basketballvolley` are all valid matches.

EDIT:

Your html form should look something like this to be able to pass your required params in your query string:

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="Item" value="ProductList" />
Search: <input type="text" name="Search" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I understand all that my problem is the URL i'm sending it to because when I create a "<form class="forms" action="" method="get" name="Search">" what would I put in the action="" where it would appear exactly like ?Item=ProductList&Search=SearchTerm. Because when I put index.php the URL it return is only **http://localhost/InventorySystem/Employee/Tools/Item?Search=** not **?Item=ProductList&Search=SearchTerm**

Comment: @anoldgangstah no need to put an action if you are referring to the current page. If you require `Item=ProductList`, then include `<input type="hidden" name="Item" value="ProductList" />` in your form.

Comment: Okay when I put blank in the action still the url isnt displaying what I want to display in the url. Err I'm really sorry dude if im giving you not too detailed information my way of doing things might be wrong I think im just gonna rewrite all these.

Comment: you are acttually correct! That thing you said works perfectly `?Item=ProductList&Search=Keyboard` I can now perform the search feature! Thank god you understood my question.

Comment: @anoldgangstah include input type hidden as I described above in my edited post. See also edited answer.

Comment: @anoldgangstah great to hear that.

Comment: @anoldgangstah no problem, programmers should help fellow programmers in times of need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're just using a SQL statement to query the product for this page.

I'd check `isset($_GET['Search'])` to know if the `Search` parameter exists. If it does then I'd append some condition to the SQL statement (`where ... = ...`). Keep in mind about sanitizing the query though, to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Example code:

```
$query = "select * from products";
if (isset($_GET['Search']))
  $query .= " where somefield=?";

$mysqli->prepare($query....);
```

Comment: I already know the part where I need to query the database, What I need to know is how to how to go about implementing the search function when your page depends on $_Get method.

Comment: What do you mean depends on the $_GET method?

Comment: I mean that I dont have an independent page or like productlist.php my productlist was displayed from get method index.php?Item=ProductList

Comment: you don't need a separate page. how are you getting data for your product list on index.php currently?

Comment: I used if(($_GET[Item]) == ProductList){ProductList();} the ProductList() performs the database query and displays it directly in to the page.

Comment: then in your `ProductList` function check `isset($_GET['Search'])` and filter your result...

Comment: Hmm I think you have a point! I knew I'm missing something. Thanks for that Idea! I'll get back to you if I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be some variation of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
  // Perform the search, probably against a back-end database.
  // For purposes of this pseudocode, I'll assume you store the results in a
  // variable named $search_result that is an array of associative arrays
  // with fields 'id' and 'name'.
?>
    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Search Results</p>
    <table>
    <?php foreach ($search_result as $result): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><a href=$base_url."/Item="<?= urlencode($result['id']) ?>">
          <?= htmlentities($result['name']) ?></a></td>
      </tr>
    </php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>

  <!-- stuff you display whether page is searched or not goes here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Item means the page that I am displaying which is the ProductList. I don't know if this solves the problem because my problem is in the URL side.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking then. It sounds like you just need to parse your $_GET parameters and take whatever appropriate action you need for each one. If isset($_GET['Search']), then write a function to generate search results. If not, then the user isn't searching, and you should generate whatever the page does if there is no search.